# Why is it subtracting 1 and doing a bitwise inverse is equivalent to doing a bitwise inverse and adding 1?

Tags: binary, twos-complement

I am studying two's complement and have come across 2 methods for converting a number's two's complement representation to its decimal representation:

1. Subtract 1 from the initial binary number, then do a bitwise inverse. Convert this new binary number to a decimal number and adjust the sign accordingly.
2. Do a bitwise inverse on the initial binary number, then add 1. Convert this new binary number to a decimal number and adjust the sign accordingly.

Why is it subtracting 1 and doing a bitwise inverse is equivalent to doing a bitwise inverse and adding 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR
if −*a*==~*a*+1, then ~*a*==−a−1 and ~(*a*−1)==−(*a*−1)-1==−*a*

Two's complement works by coding a negative number *a*<0 by 2^*n*−|*a*|=2^*n*+*a*. This way *a*+(−*a*)=2^*n* and if one ignores bits above *n*−1 the code of −*a* has he same mathematical properties  for addition as −*a*.

So the problem to find two's complement *b* of *a*, is to find a number *b* such as *a*+*b*=2^*n*.
We can see that binary complement of *a*, ~*a* *almost* has this property.

```
    a    an-1  an-2    ...  a1    a0
 + ~a   ~an-1 ~an-2    ... ~a1   ~a0
   ---------------------------------
 =          1     1    ...   1     1
```

Either *a*i=0 and ~*a*i=1 or *a*i=1 and ~*a*i=0 and *a*+~*a*=111..11=2^*n*−1
By adding one, we can see that *a*+~*a*+1=2^*n* and that two's complement of *a* is ~*a*+1.

As ~*a*+1=2^*n*−*a*
~*a*=2^*n*−*a*-1
If we replace *a* by (*a*−1), we get
~(*a*−1)=2^n−(*a*−1)−1
           = 2^n−*a*
           = ~*a*+1

So ~*a*+1 and ~(*a*-1) are identical.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the first answer explanation, but from what I know (correct me if I am wrong), let's say I have a binary number 10011. Using C2 makes it so:

**First Step:** Invert 10011 => 01100

**Second Step:** Add 1 => 01100+1= 01101

Now, when it says the binary number is coded In C2, convert to decimal. Example: 100100

**First Step:** Sub 1 100100-1=> 100011

**Second Step:** Invert 100011 => 100011